# Squeryl: KeyedEntity.id isn't updated on insert

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.0, squeryl

I have a table definition

```
class Transaction(
  val ...
) extends KeyedEntity[Long] {
  val id:Long = 0
}

val transaction = table[Transaction]("transactions")

on(transaction) {t =>
    declare(
        t.id is unique
        ... (other fields)
    )
}
```

The database table was not generated by Squeryl (I created it manually), but the "ID" column is set to PrimaryKey and AutoIncrement.

Now I'm inserting a row in this table:

```
val row = new Transaction(...)
val rowResult = transaction.insert(row)
println("Id1="+row.id+"; Id2="+rowResult.id)
```

The row is correctly inserted into the database and there an ID is assigned (!=0).
But the application prints "ID1=0; ID2=0" on the command line.

Why? And how do I get the assigned ID?

**edit:**
I did also try the table definition this way

```
class Transaction(
    val id: Long,
    ...
) extends KeyedEntity[Long]
```

Didn't make any differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I remove the declaration

```
t.id is unique
```

it works. So the problem is solved.

Is this a bug in squeryl?

Comment: It isn't a bug.  By default, any numeric id field is set to be auto-incremented.  When you specify `t.id is unique` you are overriding the default behavior.  It isn't necessary to specify that it's unique since it's a primary key, but if you wanted to you would have to include the autoincremented attribute as well `t.id is (unique, autoIncremented)`